# sudo maas-import-isos fails

Tags: maas

I am unable to run `sudo maas-import-isos`. The error message i get is

```
###
failed to download MD5SUMS for precise-x86_64.
failed to download MD5SUMS for precise-i386.
failed to get https://maas.ubuntu.com/images/query/precise/ephemeral/released-dl.current.txt
remote query of https://maas.ubuntu.com/images failed
profile raring-i386 not found, inheritance not possible
###
```

however i do have access to the outside world since the curl function succeeds.

Can someone please help??

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try `sudo maas-import-pxe-files` (for Ubuntu 12.04, 13.10 and 14.04)

You may also want to verify that you do have outside internet. Try to ping an outside server, e.g., ping www.yahoo.com or any one else you wish.